# C++ MySQL driver->connect VS2013

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, visual-studio-2013

I followed this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-cpp-en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html to install MySQL and configure it with dynamic linking.

My program compiles but when I debug it and it gets to the line where it does sql->connect it crashes with a few access violations.

I also get this:

```
+       driver  0x014b3a00 <Information not available, no symbols loaded for mysqlcppconn.dll>  sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *
```

Database.cpp

```
#include "Functions.h"
#include "Settings.h"
#include "Database.h"

#define mysqlcppconn_EXPORTS
/* MySQL Connector/C++ specific headers */
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/metadata.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset_metadata.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <warning.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

CDatabase::CDatabase(CSettings* settings)
{

    Connection *con;

    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();

    con = driver->connect("", "", "");
    con->setSchema("");

    cout << "Connected.";
}

CDatabase::~CDatabase()
{
}
```

What have I tried?

- checked the .dll files, both are x86.
- googling
- double checked all directories

My Paths:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3\lib\opt
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.3\include
```

DLLs in the output directory:

```
libmysql.dll
mysqlcppconn.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah my bad it was giving a sql error.
Didnt realise that I had to try....catch it haha!